# Data when object called in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

## Code:

```
class abc():
    def __init__(self,x):
        pass

a = abc(2)
print(a)
```

## Desired OP:

```
2
```

## Current OP:

```
<__main__.abc object at 0x000002736F8D7128>
```

How to get some data when an object is called instead of the default message about the object location

## The same way when:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3])
print(a)
```

## Gives OP

```
[1 2 3]
```

Comment: Override `__str__`/`__repr__`.

Comment: First of all you will have to actally save that value in the object...

Comment: You can check this link [`__repr__` v/s `__str__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr) here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to print the object's string representation using `print` statement that's why you are getting `<__main__.abc object at 0x000002736F8D7128>`
 If you want to modify that representation you either have to override the `__str__` or `__repr__` method.

For Example,

```
class abc():
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.X = x

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.X)
```

OR,

```
class abc():
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.X = x

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.X)
```

Now, when you call `print(abc(2))` output will be `2`.